# Javascript detail informations json

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a beginner in Javascript and I've given myself the challenge to create an online sales site. I use the fakestore.com API to generate products.
For the moment my javascript code looks like this:

```js
var meilleuresVentes = document.getElementById('mVentes');
var test = document.getElementById('test');

//request to recover the json of fakestore.com products
var requestURL = 'https://fakestoreapi.com/products';
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', requestURL);
request.open('GET', requestURL);
request.responseType = 'json';
request.send();

request.onload = function() {
  var superHeroes = request.response;
  mVentes(superHeroes)
}

//function to create a card with the information on the first 3 products
function  mVentes(prod) {
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var card = document.createElement('article');
    var image = document.createElement('img');
    var title = document.createElement('h3');
    var description = document.createElement('p');
    var price = document.createElement('h4');
    var button = document.createElement('button');

    title.textContent = prod[i]['title'];
    image.src = prod[i]['image'];
    price.textContent = prod[i]['price']+ " €";
    button.textContent = "Add to cart";

//as the descriptions were too long the following code allows to keep only the first 100 letters
    var desc = prod[i]['description'];
    var text = "";
    for(var b = 0; b < 100; b++) {
      var text = text + desc[b] 
    }
    description.textContent = text + "...";

    card.appendChild(image);
    card.appendChild(title);
    card.appendChild(description);
    card.appendChild(price);
    card.appendChild(button);
    meilleuresVentes.appendChild(card);
  }
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kumbh+Sans:wght@400;800&display=swap');
body{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Kumbh Sans', sans-serif;
}
header{
    display: flex;
    padding: 20px;
    align-items: center;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 1;
}
.hleft{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 20%;
    justify-content: end;
}
ul{
    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 50%;
    justify-content: start;
    margin-right: auto;
}
li {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.logo{
    width: 24%;
}
.avatar{
    object-fit: contain;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: 20%;
}
h1{
    font-size: 55px;
}
h2{
    font-size: 35px;
    margin: 70px;
}
.accueil{
    margin-inline: 10%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.right{
    width: 50%;
    justify-content: end;
}
.left{
    width: 50%;
}
.imgaccueil{
    width: 90%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: 10%;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    margin-left: 40px;
    max-width: 400px;
    height: 100%;
}
.baseline{
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 50px;
}
.fleche{
    position: relative;
    top: 21px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
#mVentes img{
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 400px;
}
article{
    width: 20%;
    background-color: beige;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-inline: 20px;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 20px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
#mVentes{
    display: flex;
    margin-inline: auto;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
#mVentes button{
    background-color: orangered;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#mVentes h4{
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sneakers-Buy a shoes</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/styleindex.css">
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <svg class="logo" width="138" height="20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M8.217 20c4.761 0 7.519-.753 7.519-4.606 0-3.4-3.38-4.172-6.66-4.682l-.56-.085-.279-.041-.35-.053c-2.7-.405-3.18-.788-3.18-1.471 0-.478.49-1.331 2.843-1.331 2.455 0 3.493.647 3.493 1.87v.134h4.281v-.133c0-2.389-1.35-5.238-7.774-5.238-5.952 0-7.201 2.584-7.201 4.752 0 3.097 2.763 4.086 7.223 4.675.21.028.433.054.659.081 1.669.197 3.172.42 3.172 1.585 0 1.01-1.615 1.222-3.298 1.222-2.797 0-3.784-.593-3.784-1.92v-.134H.002L0 14.926v.317c.008.79.118 1.913 1.057 2.862C2.303 19.362 4.712 20 8.217 20Zm13.21 0v-7.49c0-2.104.547-4.423 4.176-4.423 3.915 0 3.778 2.777 3.768 4.042V20h4.18v-7.768c0-2.264-.176-7.766-6.732-7.766-2.778 0-4.192.911-5.195 2.28h-.197V4.467H17.22V20h4.207Zm21.959 0c5.094 0 7.787-2.07 8.217-5.405H47.53c-.386 1.02-1.63 1.72-4.143 1.72-2.721 0-3.962-1.03-4.25-3.106h12.527c.24-2.13-.029-5.417-3.026-7.44v.005c-1.312-.915-3.056-1.465-5.251-1.465-5.24 0-8.336 2.772-8.336 7.845 0 5.17 3.02 7.846 8.336 7.846Zm4.099-9.574h-8.188c.486-1.574 1.764-2.431 4.089-2.431 2.994 0 3.755 1.267 4.099 2.431ZM70.499 20V4.457H66.29V6.74h-.176c-1.053-1.377-2.809-2.283-5.677-2.283-6.433 0-7.225 5.293-7.253 7.635v.137c0 2.092.732 7.771 7.241 7.771 2.914 0 4.684-.818 5.734-2.169h.131V20H70.5Zm-8.854-3.623c-3.996 0-4.447-3.032-4.447-4.148 0-1.21.426-4.148 4.455-4.148 3.631 0 4.374 2.044 4.374 4.148 0 2.35-.742 4.148-4.382 4.148ZM88.826 20l-6.529-9.045 6.588-6.488h-5.827l-6.836 6.756V0h-4.187v19.954h4.187V16.94l3.02-2.976L83.6 20h5.226Zm9.9 0c5.094 0 7.786-2.07 8.217-5.405h-4.074c-.387 1.02-1.63 1.72-4.143 1.72-2.721 0-3.962-1.03-4.25-3.106h12.527c.24-2.13-.029-5.417-3.026-7.44v.005c-1.312-.915-3.057-1.465-5.251-1.465-5.24 0-8.336 2.772-8.336 7.845 0 5.17 3.02 7.846 8.336 7.846Zm4.098-9.574h-8.187c.485-1.574 1.763-2.431 4.089-2.431 2.994 0 3.755 1.267 4.098 2.431ZM112.76 20v-6.97c0-2.103.931-4.542 4.05-4.542 1.33 0 2.393.236 2.785.346l.67-3.976c-.728-.16-1.626-.392-2.757-.392-2.665 0-3.622.794-4.486 2.282h-.262V4.466h-4.21V20h4.21Zm17.221 0c4.761 0 7.519-.753 7.519-4.606 0-3.4-3.38-4.172-6.66-4.682l-.56-.085-.279-.041-.349-.053c-2.701-.405-3.181-.788-3.181-1.471 0-.478.49-1.331 2.843-1.331 2.455 0 3.493.647 3.493 1.87v.134h4.282v-.133c0-2.389-1.35-5.238-7.775-5.238-5.952 0-7.201 2.584-7.201 4.752 0 3.097 2.763 4.086 7.224 4.675.21.028.432.054.658.081 1.669.197 3.172.42 3.172 1.585 0 1.01-1.615 1.222-3.298 1.222-2.796 0-3.784-.593-3.784-1.92v-.134h-4.319l-.001.301v.317c.008.79.117 1.913 1.056 2.862 1.246 1.257 3.655 1.895 7.16 1.895Z" fill="#1D2026" fill-rule="nonzero"/></svg>
        <ul>
            <li>Collections</li>
            <li>Men</li>
            <li>Women</li>
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="hleft">
            <svg width="22" height="20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M20.925 3.641H3.863L3.61.816A.896.896 0 0 0 2.717 0H.897a.896.896 0 1 0 0 1.792h1l1.031 11.483c.073.828.52 1.726 1.291 2.336C2.83 17.385 4.099 20 6.359 20c1.875 0 3.197-1.87 2.554-3.642h4.905c-.642 1.77.677 3.642 2.555 3.642a2.72 2.72 0 0 0 2.717-2.717 2.72 2.72 0 0 0-2.717-2.717H6.365c-.681 0-1.274-.41-1.53-1.009l14.321-.842a.896.896 0 0 0 .817-.677l1.821-7.283a.897.897 0 0 0-.87-1.114ZM6.358 18.208a.926.926 0 0 1 0-1.85.926.926 0 0 1 0 1.85Zm10.015 0a.926.926 0 0 1 0-1.85.926.926 0 0 1 0 1.85Zm2.021-7.243-13.8.81-.57-6.341h15.753l-1.383 5.53Z" fill="#69707D" fill-rule="nonzero"/></svg>
            <img class="avatar"src="images/image-avatar.png" alt="image of the avatar">
        </div>
    </header>
    <hr>
    <section class="accueil">
        <div class="left">
            <h1>Welcome to the best website to buy sneakers</h1>
            <div class="baseline">
                <svg class="fleche" width="12" height="18" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M11 1 3 9l8 8" stroke="#1D2026" stroke-width="3" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"/></svg>
                <h5>View our collections</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <img class="imgaccueil" src="images/image-product-1.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
    </section>
    <h2>Meilleures ventes</h2>
    <div id="mVentes">
    </div>
    <div id="test"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like that when I press the button the program adds the product in the cart but I can't get the information of the product.
Thanks for your help!
PS I am French so sorry if the translations are not optimal... :/

Comment: You will have to pass that item to your cart function when someones clicks it and use array  to push items and show array of items.

Comment: The size of the array will be no of the items in your cart and you can remove items by popping element from the array.

Comment: Thank you but as I create several items when we click on an item it adds in the cart only the last item to be passed in the loop of the function and not the one on which we click.

Comment: I think you need to upload your whole code(at least JS file) then only it will be easy for me to understand your problem in a clear manner.

Comment: Of course ! Like that ?

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question in sentence format. See [ask].

Comment: Hey, @FoucauldBert you haven't implemented onclick event on the add to cart button or haven't created any function then how are you expecting, it should work for you.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think everything is working now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can keep the id of the product as a data-attribute on the card.

While adding a product to the cart we can get the product-id from the data-attribute as explained below code and can either make an API call ([https://fakestoreapi.com/products/{id}](https://fakestoreapi.com/products/1)) example https://fakestoreapi.com/products/1 or in case we are caching the results of API, can filter the items based on product id.
***HTML***

```
<article data-id="1">
<img src="example-image" alt="product-image" />
  <h3>title</h3>
  <p>description</p>
  <h4>$123</h4>
  <button onClick="addToCart(event)">
    Add to cart
  </button>
</article>
```

***JS***

```
function addToCart(e){
    const id = e.target.parentNode.dataset.id;
    const url = `https://fakestoreapi.com/products/${id}`;
    //make api call or get from cache and handle logic for cart display
}
```

Comment: Thanks but excuse me, how to put the data-attribute to the article in the javascript ?

Comment: Add 'card.setAttribute("data-id", prod[i]['title'])' right after we declare card variable in javascript.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I think everything is working now !